# Sort positive elements by MergeSort

Tags: c, sorting, mergesort

My task:

In a one-dimensional dynamic array, sort the positive elements by merging.
Why doesn't it work?
Why does it stop sorting those elements that I have written to the new array?
The first function is the input and input check functions.
Progress: I enter an array, allocate memory, enter elements, delete all negative ones, overwrite this array into a new dynamic array, send the data of the new array to the function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int input() {
    int var;
    while ((scanf_s("%d", &var) == 0) || getchar() != '\n') {
        printf("wrong input! try again\n");
        rewind(stdin);
    }
    return var;
}

void Merge(int *A, int first, int last) {
    int middle, start, final, j;
    int *mas;
    middle = (first + last) / 2; 
    start = first; 
    final = middle + 1; 
    mas = (int *)malloc((last - first) * sizeof(int));
    for (j = first; j <= last; j++) 
        if ((start <= middle) && ((final > last) || (A[start] < A[final]))) {
            *(mas + j - first) = A[start];
            start++;
        } else {
            *(mas + j - first) = A[final];
            final++;
        }
    
    for (j = first; j <= last; j++)
        A[j] = *(mas + j - first);
}

void MergeSort(int *A, int first, int last) {
    {
        if (first < last) {
            MergeSort(A, first, (first + last) / 2); 
            MergeSort(A, (first + last) / 2 + 1, last); 
            Merge(A, first, last);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int i, n, j;
    int *arr;
    int *arrp;
    printf("Input num of elements in mass: ");
    n = check();
    arr = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("Element %d = ", i + 1); 
        arr[i] = input();
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d  ", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (arr[i] < 0) {
            for (j = i; j < n - 1; j++) {
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
            }
            i--;
            n--;
        }
    }
    arrp = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        arrp[i] = arr[i];
        printf("%d  ", arrp[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    MergeSort(arrp, 0, n); 
    printf("\nSorted array: ");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    free(arrp);
    free(arr);
}
```

Comment: `malloc((last - first)` - don't you need one more? (think e.g. last=first)

Comment: @500-InternalServerError `first` is inclusive but `last` is _exclusive_ -- typical in C and C++ list indexing.

Comment: @Dúthomhas: `for (j = first; j <= last; j++)`

Comment: I didn’t say OP’s code was correct...

Answer (score 2):

So, a number of suggestions here to help.

### Helper functions for the win!

The idea to have helper functions is a good one.

A lot of programming is knowing where to abstract complexity. You noticed that getting an integer input takes a few lines of code and abstracted that into a helper. Good job!

We’re going to run with this.

### Bad input: You cannot `rewind(stdin)`

For homework assignments in general, do not try to resynchronize after bad input. Unless otherwise stated in your instructions you can typically *assume* that all input is correct.

Brownie points for detecting bad input, but if you do, just fail, possibly with a diagnostic message.

Here is a little function that helps with that:

```
void Error(const char* message) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", message);
    exit(1);
}
```

Now we can have a clean helper function to obtain an integer from input:

```
int InputInteger(void) {
    int n;
    if (!scanf("%d", &n)) 
        Error("Expected an integer");
    return n;
}
```

Now the `main()` function is a very readable:

```
int main(void) {
    
    printf("How many elements? ");
    int n = InputInteger();
    if (n < 2) Error("Expected a value ≥ 2");
```

Notice how I threw in a condition for a reasonable value of `n`? You can check for any `n` you wish. Just make sure it is greater-than zero, since you cannot dynamically allocate zero or any negative number of bytes.

### `malloc()`: check for errors

In C you do not need to cast to the target type. (I always do anyway, since I am constantly writing code that I expect to compile in either C or C++. Some C purists lose their minds whenever they see an explicit cast attached to an invocation of `malloc()`, though.)

You *absolutely should*, however, check that the allocation succeeded (and barf it fails).

```
    int* arr = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    if (!arr) Error("Memory allocation failure");
    
    for (int i = 0;  i < n;  i++)
        arr[i] = InputInteger();
```

Beautiful, no?

Notice how we don’t care about freeing `arr` if `InputInteger()` causes termination. That happens automagically when your program terminates.

### Finishing `main()`, a top-down thinking process

Notice that you need to perform a couple of complex operations, one of them repeatedly. Let’s finish `main()` as if those helpers have already been written:

```
int main(void) {
  
    printf("How many elements? ");
    int n = InputInteger();
    if (n < 2) Error("Expected a value ≥ 2");
    
    int* arr = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    if (!arr) Error("Memory allocation failure");
    
    for (int i = 0;  i < n;  i++)
        arr[i] = InputInteger();
    
    PrintArray("Before sorting", arr, n);

    n = RemoveNegativeElements(arr, n);
    if (n < 2) Error("Expected two or more non-negative elements");
    
    PrintArray("Non-negative elements", arr, n);
    
    MergeSort(arr, n);
    
    PrintArray("Sorted", arr, n);
    
    free(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Notice how clean this makes things. Notice also how there are no auxiliary arrays created in all that. This maintains the abstraction boundaries:

- Merge sort needs an auxiliary array, but the code that *uses* the merge sort shouldn’t have to care how merge sort works.
- Removing negative elements from the array doesn’t actually require an auxiliary array, but again, the code that *uses* it shouldn’t care whether it does or does not.

Now that we have an idea of what we would *like* things to look like, let’s create the helper functions:

```
void PrintArray(const char* title, int* arr, int n) {
    printf("%s:", title);
    for (int i = 0;  i < n;  i++)
        printf(" %d", arr[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

int RemoveNegativeElements(int* arr, int n) { // returns new size of array
    // Enough freebies. Time to think.
}
```

### Merge Algorithm

The merge algorithm is *used* by merge sort, but it is (drumroll...) *a helper function*.

The merge function, by definition, merges two separate arrays into a third target array. It should look like this:

```
void Merge(
    int* A, int A_size,
    int* B, int B_size,
    int* C
)
```

Its behavior is exactly this:

```
// first loop: merge
while both (A has uncopied elements) and (B has uncopied elements):
  if next A <= next B:
    append next A to C
  else:
    append next B to C
    
// second loop: append any remaining A elements
while A has uncopied elements:
  append next A to C
  
// third loop: append any remaining B elements
while B has uncopied elements:
  append next B to C
```

I am sure you can think of a simple way to keep track of where you are in `A`, `B`, and `C` for these loops.

One thing you should notice about this is that the Merge algorithm itself:

- ***does not*** allocate any auxiliary memory
- ***does not*** work over a single array

That is, it has as input two arrays and as output a *different* array.

##### The Merge algorithm is *stable*

...making Merge Sort a **stable sort algorithm**. What this means is that elements that compare equivalent keep their same relative ordering. For example, suppose we wanted to sort the following list:

```
2.3  3.9  4.7  3.14  1.2
```

If we were to sort by whole value, ignoring any fractional value, we would get:

```
1.2  2.3  3.9  3.14  4.7
```

Notice that elements that compare equivalent maintain their original ordering. `3.9` and `3.14` both have a whole value of 3, so they are equivalent using our weird comparison criterion. Yet when sorted the `3.9` stays *before* the `3.14`. This is what is meant by a **stable sort algorithm**.

The comparison in the Merge algorithm maintains that stability using the `<=` operator, so that elements in `A` are chosen before any equivalent elements in `B`.

<sup>When I first wrote this answer I accidentally wrote `<` instead of `<=`, which broke the stability of the sort. User **chaqrlie** kindly noticed and fixed it.</sup>

(Common in C and C++ is to provide a comparison function that returns strictly less-than, in which case we would rewrite the first loop as:

```
while both (A has uncopied elements) and (B has uncopied elements):
  if next B < next A:
    append next B to C
  else:
    append next A to C
```

Take a minute to convince yourself that this has same behavior as what we had before.)

### Merge Sort Algorithm

Now we are ready to tackle the merge *sort*. There are quite a few very interesting variations of merge sort, but I’ll stick with the classic top-down version you are trying to implement.

The idea is to split an array into a left half and a right half. When we have guaranteed that each half is sorted, we then merge the two halves back together.

The “guarantee” part is where we get recursive. For example, if I split:

```
6 7 5 3 9 1
```

into halves:

```
6 7 5   3 9 1
```

neither half is sorted. So we need to recursively merge sort each half. Splitting that left side into halves gives us:

```
6   7 5
```

Conveniently, a single-element array is already sorted. Calling merge sort on such an array should do nothing, ending the recursion cycle.

We are unsure about the other half, though, as a two-element array could be unsorted (as it is in this example). So merge sort each side again, which once again gives us our base case: single element arrays. Merging the two single element arrays together gets us:

```
5 7
```

And merging:

```
6   5 7
```

gives us:

```
5 6 7
```

This should be evident: the merge algorithm gets two arrays (`6` and `5` `7`) and combines them into an output array containing `5` `6` `7`.

There are a number of fancy ways to handle the intermediate array(s), but I suggest this one, as it makes life very simple and suggests some very nice optimizations beyond the most obvious:

- make a copy of the *left* half (in an auxiliary array)
- use the right half of the original array
- put the results of the merge algorithm in the original array

Visually, that is:

```
6 7 5 3 9 1  (original array input to merge sort algorithm)
      ↑      (right half begins here)

6 7 5        (copy of left half)
```

Let’s jump ahead to where the left and right halves are already sorted and merge them:

```
x x x 1 3 9    1 x x 1 3 9    1 3 x 1 3 9    1 3 5 1 3 9    1 3 5 6 3 9    1 3 5 6 7 9     1 3 5 6 7 9
↑     ↑          ↑     ↑          ↑     ↑          ↑   ↑            ↑ ↑              ↑↑              ↑ ↑
                                                                                           
5 6 7          5 6 7          5 6 7          5 6 7          5 6 7          5 6 7           5 6 7
↑              ↑              ↑                ↑                ↑                ↑               ↑
```

Merging the left and right halves into `arr` will always work. Take a bit to convince yourself this is true.

This isn’t the One and Only True Way™ to do this, but it has some pretty amazing advantages, not least of which is reduced space needs and reduced copying right out of the box.

So, here is our updated merge sort algorithm:

```
if n < 2:
  return

k = (n+1)/2  // k := length of left half, index of first element in right half

recursively merge sort the left half  (arr[0] to arr[k-1])
recursively merge sort the right half (arr[k] to arr[n-1])

aux = create a copy of the left half
Merge aux and right half, putting the result in arr
free aux
```

I can’t tell you how hard it is to describe this without just giving you the answer in code. It is *that* simple. Mess with it a bit and it will eventually be clear.

Remember, sometimes it just takes a little while to wrap your mind around it.

### Arrays and Pointers and Indices

Helpful to you will be to review how arrays work, and how you can use a pointer with or without an integer index do do stuff.

For example, given `int* arr` — a pointer to one or more integers (in an array, right?),  you can index the `n`th value with:

```
arr[n]
```

That is friendly C-language syntax for:

```
*(arr + n)
```

So when you want to pass the *right half* of `arr` to `Merge()`, you can simply say:

```
Merge(...,  arr+k, n-k, ...)
```

Because `arr[k]` is the first element of the right half of `arr`, right? And the right half has `n-k` elements, right?

It is also entirely okay to increment a pointer. So you can easily say:

```
*C++ = ...
```

It is just fine to use an integer index, though:

```
int i = 0;  // Index into A
int j = 0;  // Index into B
int k = 0;  // Index into C
...
C[k++] = ...
```

Food for thought.

### Those various optimizations I’ve been hinting at...?

They exist, but I wouldn’t worry about them today. Future you, however, may wish to consider creating a public `MergeSort()` function that allocates all the memory you’ll need (half the input array size!), just *once*, and call a `MergeSort_Impl()` function that just reuses it over and over. This reduces dynamic memory to a single `malloc()` and a single `free()`.

That’s the main optimization. If you use the structure I gave you above, you can also avoid copying elements by eliminating the last loop in the merge algorithm, since those elements are already there. Finally, you can also avoid copying some elements into the auxiliary array if you skip over leading elements in the left side that are already sorted relative to the right side.

At this point, however, these optimizations are *adding* complexity to the merge and merge sort algorithms. Hence, save them for future you, when your employer wants a nice, fast, highly-optimized merge sort.

Oh, and future you will also want to put an upper limit on the number of times you can recurse.

And switch to Insertion Sort if the array is less than some 50 to 100 elements. Under the L1 cache threshold, nothing beats Insertion Sort in blazing speed.

### Compiler warnings to the max-ish

At the risk of babbling to myself at this point in such a long post, I should add this final hint:

It really helps you to turn your compiler warnings up. For MSVC you should have them at a minimum of `/W3`. For GCC and Clang make sure to have `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors -Werror` all set.

Whenever the compiler spits out a list of errors, take the *first one* that gives you a line number in your source code and go look at it. Fix it and recompile. Repeat until all the errors are gone.

Learning to do this takes a little time, but you will find that it quickly becomes very easy. Once you are very familiar with the language you often won’t even need to look at the actual error message, as you will know what mistake you made just by looking at the code.

Comment: I took the liberty to fix a few typos... I am surprised you use `k = n/2 + 1` instead of `k = (n + 1) / 2` or even just `k = n/2`. This will create imbalanced halves, for example 4 -> 1, 3

Comment: Thanks. I, uh, think my brain may have broken on `k`, seeing as I just typed this all off the top of my head. I should fix that too.

Comment: BTW, thanks for the fix in the merge. Should I mention anything about this being a stable sort? (And how my mistake broke that?)

Comment: Mentioning the stable sort property of merge sort is a good idea. the `<=` ensures that elements that compare identical are taken from the left half first, in the order in which they appear.